# Extract value of a variable that apears at least twice on two factor levels of an other variable of R dataframe

Tags: r, variables, extract

I have a data frame (`df`) like:

`database  minrna  genesymbol 
    A        mir-1   abc
    A        mir-2   bcc
    B        mir-1   abc
    B        mir-3   xyb
    c        mir-1   abc`

I want to extract mirna that is predicted at least by two databases. For example in the above `df`, `mir-1' is predicted by database`A`,`B`and`C` and hence, the result I want would be:

`database  minrna genesymbol 
    A        mir-1   abc
    B        mir-1   abc
    c        mir-1   abc`

I have tried to search similar questions but I couldn't find something similar to this. Could you please help me to solve this out. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show what did you try already?

Comment: I tried one option using dplyr and its working, I like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can count number of unique `database` for each `minrna` and filter based on that.

This can be done in base R :

```
subset(df, ave(database, minrna, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) >= 2)

#  database minrna genesymbol
#1        A  mir-1        abc
#3        B  mir-1        abc
#5        c  mir-1        abc
```

In `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(minrna) %>% filter(n_distinct(database) >= 2)
```

Or with `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[uniqueN(database) >=2], minrna]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(database = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "c"), minrna = c("mir-1", 
"mir-2", "mir-1", "mir-3", "mir-1"), genesymbol = c("abc", "bcc", 
"abc", "xyb", "abc")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `group_by` function from {dplyr} package, I will let you figure out the details as a form of exercise.

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/